# LibreOffice Writer messes up IPA

Tags: fonts, libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

I copied and pasted this into LibreOffice Writer

> ɑt͡ʃɛxɑ qɔbo qɔɛɾɘ

It came out like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMc8s.png)

Looks like it's just a display issue: when I copy the text out of LOW again, it looks the same as the original, so it's not getting corrupted.

What's going on? Why won't it display IPA correctly?

Comment: Are you using the latest version 5.1.4 or 5.2?

Comment: I tried different versions on Windows and Linux and it worked fine.  What font is it using?  Does it make a difference if you do `Edit -> Paste Special -> Unformatted Text`?  Try setting the text to a Unicode IPA font such as [Doulos SIL](http://software.sil.org/doulos/download/).